# Batch loop for password

Tags: loops, batch-file, password-protection, forgot-password

I need help writing a script for batch. 
I forgot the password for a file, it's a simple password 4 chars ( 1234, asdf, qwer) .

The command line is this:

> C:\Users\DB> .\open.exe --file=db1.bin --password=asdf
>   Logging to C:\Users\DB\open.log
>   Error: failed to load: invalid password

I managed to generate a list of passwords (`pass.txt`) since the number is either 1st or last in string and only lower case but still there are couple thousands. Is there any way to automate this?

Comment: The password is ****

Comment: You can use a `FOR /F` command to read the password list and insert that as a variable into your command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over a text file, use a `for /f` loop.

```
for /f %%A in (pass.txt) do open.exe --file=db1.bin --password=%%A
```

If you want it to track where you are in the file, add an `echo`.

```
for /f %%A in (pass.txt) do (
    echo Now trying %%A
    open.exe --file=db1.bin --password=%%A
)
```

Comment: Happy to help. If my solution worked for you, please click the check mark next to my answer.

Comment: just optional, can be added a line to the script that will show which password is using ? using: asdf

Comment: @RamonaBota - Done

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
(
 for %%a in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  for %%b in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
   for %%c in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
    for %%d in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
     echo(%%a%%b%%c%%d
    )
   )
  )
 )
)>pass.txt
```

needs about half a minute to generate all possible 808496 passwords

```
{letter | number}{letter}{letter}{letter | number}
```

where only start OR end may be a number). If both start AND end could be a number, just skip the last two lines (876096 passwords)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the effort, however I already generated the list with a program, the issue is running the *.exe with every password until the correct password is found.  open.exe --file=db1.bin --password=(line by line from pass.txt) . I need a way to automatize this.

Comment: Stephan gave you the answer. Replace the `echo(%%a%%b%%c%%d` line with your command line.

Comment: I'm sorry either I don't understand either is something wrong, replacing echo(%%a%%b%%c%%d  doesn't resolve my issue, I don't want to regenerate the input list, as I already have, mine is a little shorter since I know the password doesn't contains duplicate letters also . "open.exe --file=db1.bin --password=here I need to place a password from the input.txt"